# where do blazor wasm file writes go?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

as a fun experiment (expected a notsupported exception) I did this is App.razor

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
    

        string[] lines =
    {
        "First line", "Second line", "Third line" 
    };

    await File.WriteAllLinesAsync("WriteLines.txt", lines);

     string[] lines2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"WriteLines.txt");
}
```

and it works fine. Where did the data go?

Comment: When in doubt, use [Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: @GSerg assumes that the file was written to the file system and not to some in browser magic space. Anyway procmon doesnt see the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blazor has access to a memory based filesystem (memfs). I can't find much info about it, it's somewhere on the border between Mono and Blazor.

You can for instance do `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("/");` and see (only) the WriteLines.txt file you just created.

> Where did the data go?

Somewhere in the memory of the Browser.

Comment: I found out the files dont persist so that seems right