# What's the valid subset of .NET Core (6) for Blazor WebAssembly (WASM)?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor Server the entire .NET Core library is supported.
In the Blazor WebAssembly Project (to my knowledge) there is only a subset of .NET is available.

This kinda makes sense, like for example File I/O doesn't make sense in the browser sandbox.

Just for the sake of experimenting I tried executing this inside a Blazor WASM Project:

```
var psname = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
```

This will cause the *page.razor* to crash.

So now I wonder if/where there is information/documentation on which native .NET classes and namespaces are actually supported inside Blazor WASM, so I don't have to *guess* what could make sense and what not.

I was already googling and searching learn.microsoft.com for a while now but couldn't find more than this statement

> The app is restricted to the capabilities of the browser

from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and this mention https://stackoverflow.com/a/69182346/17562157

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a list, but I'm waiting to be surprised. You do actually [have file I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70776649/60761), just no files to use it on.